# Possible to deploy service to GKE Autopilot cluster without YAML?

Tags: kubernetes, cluster, google-kubernetes-engine, yaml, google-cloud-run

Is it possible to deploy to GKE Autopilot cluster without YAML and just command line? I have inherited a project where deployment generates command line to deploy to CloudRun. I am in the process of migrating from CloudRun to GKE Autopilot and I would like to not need to parse or generate YAML files just for the purpose of deploying a service to GKE Autopilot. Is there a way to deploy with just command line like I can with CloudRun?

Comment: You can use [`kubectl run`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run) to create a Pod in a similar way to `gcloud run deploy` but the command deploys only Pods (and you may want to use Deployments|Services etc.). You can use [`kubectl create`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#create) to create Deployments|Services etc. but this command supports fewer args (e.g. no `--env`). Just as with Cloud Run, you should consider creating YAML (or JSON) configs (or associated tools) to leverage the full power of the platform.

Comment: Given that Cloud Run is an implementation of [knative](https://cloud.google.com/knative), you may want to investigate using [Cloud Run for Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/architecture-overview). **I've not used Anthos** but IIUC it provides a way to deploy Cloud Run to Kubernetes clusters.